# Find the arity of any function

Tags: functions

First an example: `f[x_,y_]:=x+y` would have arity 2 because it takes 2 inputs while the function `g[x]:=0` has arity 1, even though it doesn't change with the input. Is there a way to find the arity of a function? Something like a symbol `Arity` that evaluates `Arity[f]` to `2`.

Comment: possibly useful: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/792850